# Make all classes that implement an interface automatically subscribe to a specific static event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm using the event-based design pattern and I want to know if there's a simple and clean way to make all classes that implement a certain interface also subscribe to a public static event declared on another class. I will try to express what I'm trying to do with a simple code:

```
public interface IPlayControl
{
    void OnStart();
    void OnStop();
}

public class ClassWithEvent : SomeOtherClass
{
    //this event needs to be subscribed to OnStart/OnStop methods of IPlayControl
    public static event Action ActionStarted, ActionStopped;
}

public class Subscriber : IPlayControl
{
    public void OnStart() {}
    public void OnStop() {}
}
```

I want all classes like Subscriber to automatically subscribe their OnStart and OnStop methods to those single static ActionStarted, ActionStopped events of the ClassWithEvent.

So instead of registering them everytime like:

```
ClassWithEvent.ActionStarted += OnStart;
ClassWithEvent.ActionStopped += OnStop;
```

I think it would be easier and look cleaner without adding these lines to every class.

I feel like it would be an unconventional way of doing this but should I do it manually by checking all types that implement this interface and subscribing their methods with a loop? I found this code on another post.

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
.Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you add an abstract class implementing that interface and let all classes inherit from it? Then you could subscribe to the event there.

Comment: So when you call `new Subscriber()` you want it to automagically hook up the events from some instance of `ClassWithEvent`? I personally think this is asking for trouble one way or another

Comment: Accidentally leaving instances subscribed to a static event is a somewhat common cause of memory leaks (since that reference keeps the objects alive even after all other parts of the code have abandoned their references), and this design seems to take it further by not even making the subscription obvious. I'd suggest a rethink.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can do that too, just wanted to know if there's an internal mechanism to achieve this without workarounds. Thank you for your answer, I will consider doing this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can't we just make them automatically unsubscribe as well on dispose?

Comment: @00110001 yes that's what I'm looking for. I think you are mentioning the possible problem Damien told me about.

Comment: So now you also need an implementation of Dispose and it's looking more and more like you need a base class (abstract, as Tim mentioned) as well as/instead of the interface.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks to both you and Tim, then I will change my design to use a base abstract class instead to avoid memory leaks as well.